# WHMCS 7.2: RewriteRule doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, whmcs

Problem start when I upgraded WHMCS from 6.3 to 7.2. All my rewriterules working except this one:

```
RewriteRule ^en/$ index.php?language=english  [NC,L,QSA]
```

I can open page `www.example.com/index.php?language=english` wthout problem.

But when I try to open `www.example.com/en/` I get `404 error`

WHMCS has poor language handling and this was my way fixing it. It used to work great under v6.3 but not under v7.2.
I have asked on WHMCS forum but had no answer. I asked WHMCS directly but they said this is third party modyfication and they not support that. 
You are my last hope!

Answer (score 0):

These rules worked for me:

```
# Redirects www.example.com/en/ to 
# www.example.com/index.php?language=english

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} en\/$
RewriteRule ^en/$ index.php?language=english  [NC,L,QSA]

# Redirects sub pages: www.example.com/en/serverstatus.php 
# to correct URL www.example.com/serverstatus.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} en\/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^en/(.*) $1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Did that worked in WHMCS version 7.2? When I use this it shows me 404.

Comment: @Solver yes 7.2. Make sure Rules are working in general, like adding simple redirect, and also .htaccess has RewriteEngine on